# Generate variable number of strings (error message "Constant expression required")

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am creating a probability macro which has user enter an integer greater than zero. This integer then creates the same number of strings as its value (if integer is 5, 5 strings are created, then the strings `"Player1"`, `"Player2"`...`"Player5"`) are created. What is the easiest way to do this?

Right now I am using:

```
Sub FunctionPlayersCount()
a = 1
Dim Player(1 To Player)
Do Until a = Players
    a = a + 1 ' add 1 each time, approaching Players value
    Player(Player) = Player & a
    MsgBox Player & a
End Sub
```

When I run this function I get:

> > Compile error:
> >
> > Constant expression required

Comment: Which `Player` is which? This is extremely poor code, reminiscent of George Foreman naming all of his male children George. When the wife says "Hey, George!", which one of them is she addressing? Her husband, her oldest child, her youngest child, or one of the several in between oldest and youngest? When you refer to `Player` in `Player(Player) = Player`, which `Player` is which? Choose better variable names to use, such as `Dim Players(1 to NumPlayers)`, try again, and then come back if you have problems. You also can't reference an array using a string + a numeral.

Comment: Dim Player ( 1 to Player) ... oh my god!

Answer (score 0):

You can't `Dim 1 to n`, but you can `Redim` :

Something like :

```
   Dim Player(1 To 15) 
   Dim intMaxPlayer as Integer
   intMaxPlayer = 10
    ...
   ReDim player(1 to intMaxPlayer)
```

Also, `Players` is not defined in your `Do Until` loop

Comment: I can't comment so I've posted... And there was no comment yet... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the point here, but I don't see why you need an array. This will create x strings "Player1" "Player2" ... "Playerx":

```
Sub FunctionPlayersCount()

Dim a As Integer
a = 1

Do While a <= NumPlayers

    MsgBox "Player" & CStr(a)
    a = a + 1 ' add 1 each time, approaching NumPlayers value

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array based on the number of players. You'll need to use `ReDim` in order to use a variable for the array size:

   ```
   intPlayers = 5
   ReDim Players(1 To intPlayers) As String
   ```
2. Use a `For` loop to populate the array...

   ```
   For i = 1 To UBound(Players)
       Players(i) = "Player" & i
   Next
   ```

Now you have a five-element array named `Players` that contains your five `"PlayerX"` strings.